# Datagirdview and tabcontrol issue

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, datagridview

I am experiencing a strange behavior in my winforms .net 4 application. I have a form with a tabcontrol having two tabpages, user selects data on tabpage1 and clicks GO button, there is a dataGridView control which is bound to a results of user selection (a datatable). After I set datasource of datagridview, I am adding a row at top(0 index) of my grid's datasource, then I am applying some formatting on that row (datagirdview.rows[0]).

I can see my formatting applied to the row in debugger, but as soon as tab selection code runs, my row formatting(isFrozen, BackColor etc) is gone.

When I selects the tabpage first and bind set datasource of gird and formatting afterwards, it works fine.

only newly added row is loosing formatting, I have a similar application in which I am adding a row like this, but it is working fine, in current application I am using a backgroundWorker and running this code from RunWorkerCompleted, while in previous application I am not using backGroundWorker.

Below is the code

```
 void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
        {
            if (((DataTable)e.Result).Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                //tabControl1.SelectTab(tabPage2); if I call from here then row formatting retains
                grdDistProcessing.DataSource = ((DataTable)e.Result);
                formatGrid();
                loadStoresGrid();
                AddTotalsRowInEnd();
                SetTotalsOfTotalRow();
                tabControl1.SelectTab(tabPage2);
            }
        }

        this.tsStatus.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Here is AddTotalsRowInEnd Method:

```
 private void AddTotalsRowInEnd()
    {
        Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
        DataRow dr = ((DataTable)grdDistProcessing.DataSource).NewRow();
        dr.ItemArray = ((DataTable)grdDistProcessing.DataSource).Rows[0].ItemArray;
        dr["Itemlookupcode"] = "Grand Totals";
        dr["Size"] = "";
        dr["COLORS"] = "";
        dr["DESCRIPTIONS"] = "";

        ((DataTable)grdDistProcessing.DataSource).Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        grdDistProcessing.Rows[0].Frozen = true;
        grdDistProcessing.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
        grdDistProcessing.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        grdDistProcessing.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.Font = f;
        grdDistProcessing.Rows[0].ReadOnly = true;
        grdDistProcessing.Refresh();
    }
```

and Here is my DoWork:

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BackgroundWorker bWorkder = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            DistVariablesTransfer dtr = e.Argument as DistVariablesTransfer;
            bWorkder.ReportProgress(10);
            cProcess pro = new cProcess();
            e.Result = pro.loadDistribution(dtr.pWarehouseID, dtr.pStores, dtr.pStyle, dtr.pColor, dtr.pSize, dtr.pDateFrom, dtr.pDateTo, dtr.pIncOrdQtyForSrc, dtr.PCheckDestinationTranferOut);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have this same issue. In my application I have five tabs. Each of the first four tabs in the application contain datagridviews. The first three work flawlessly. However, the datagridview in the fourth tab exibits the same issue as described above. The first load it is missing the background colors that are set, but in all subsequent loads the formatting appears. Turning on double buffer hasn't helped. Will post here if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
grdDistProcessing.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
grdDistProcessing.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

Use the CellFormatting event (Display category) for grdDistProcessing, like this:

```
private void grdDistProcessing_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
   e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
   e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;

}
```

It should render faster too.

Comment: Its been two years and I switched company,  but that application is still in production :) I had to select tab first as I did not find any solution on that time.