# Setting the value of cell in datagridview not working in form load

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, form-load

This is my code for setting the value in `datagridview` cell:

```
For i = 0 To dvJOBranch.Rows.Count - 1
        dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells.Item("XS").Value = 0
        dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells.Item("S").Value = 0
        dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells.Item("M").Value = 0
        dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells.Item("L").Value = 0
        dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells.Item("XL").Value = 0
Next
```

Its working in button event, shown form event, but not in form load, and there are no errors.

My question is why it does not work in form load?

Comment: is there an error on the form load?

Comment: theres no error in the form load, but I already make a work around and now it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are using the `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` functionnality and even if you set the `DataSource` property, the `DatagridView` won't create columns until the grid is displayed.

It could explain why it's not working in `formload` (grid is not initialized yet) and it works after (with shown event for example).

So it's possible that:

- you try to access items that do not exist yet (but the code should raise an exception)
- or you access valid rows or columns, but they are replaced when the grid is displayed the first time or bound again to a data source,  and so your code has no effect (probably your case since you do not mention an exception).

Using `form_shown` is maybe a possible workaround, but I recommend you to use the [`DataGridView.DataBindingComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx) event which is more especially designed to handle this situation.

See also these related issues (same cause):

- [Why DataGridColumn not getting removed from DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359031/why-datagridcolumn-not-getting-removed-from-datagridview/18443116#18443116)
- [Datagirdview and tabcontrol issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908630/datagirdview-and-tabcontrol-issue/17910352#17910352)
- [Strange issue with a datagridview and a tabcontrol C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030531/strange-issue-with-a-datagridview-and-a-tabcontrol-c-sharp/17033258#17033258)
- [DataGridView has no columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985418/datagridview-has-no-columns/16991919#16991919)